# Build Android app in command-line with Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, gradlew

I installed Android Studio on my Mac. I have an android project. I'd like to build it in command-line. If I try to build, or even just get the available tasks:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

I got this error:

```sh
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I don't want to install a new JDK. I can build the app in Android Studio. How can I use the JDK installed by Android Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this article you can find a solutiuon:
https://medium.com/@peter.configcat/build-your-android-app-from-command-line-with-android-studio-on-mac-ee1f7434709b

Add Android Studio JDK to your PATH. Add this to your `.zshenv`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=”$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH”
```

`./gradlew tasks` and `./gradlew assmebleDebug` should work.